# Probability: Gamma Function vs Gamma Distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, gamma-function

Could someone help me with setting up the function of this question. I've been setting it up with the gamma distribution function but kept getting the wrong answer.

[image]

What I did was I used the Gamma Distribution function to evaluate the integral from 0 to 1, but the answer uses the Gamma Function only, I am confused about this and don't know why the gamma distribution function is NOT used in this case.

Here is the distribution function I used:

[image]

And Here is the answer:
[image]

Note:
[image]

Comment: Can you post the Gamma function you are using. The reason I'm asking is because there are different versions of the Gamma function so it helps to know which one you are using. Also, post the answer.

Comment: posted everything

Comment: OK, let's take it one step at a time. You know that $\Gamma(2)=1$ right?

Comment: There is a property of the Gamma function that says that if $\alpha$ is a positive integer, then $\Gamma(\alpha) = (\alpha-1)!$. So, since $\alpha=2$, $\Gamma(\alpha)=(2-1)!=1$

Comment: So, substitute the values of $\Gamma(\alpha)$, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ into your equation for f(x) and you will get the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you're not getting helpful responses is because you need to show your work, rather than simply stating that you did the work.  **In order to advise you, we need to see what you are doing**.  If you do not know how to typeset your work, then you need to learn how to do it.

In the solution, the gamma distribution **is** used.  When $\alpha = 2$ and $\beta = 1$, $\Gamma(\alpha) = \Gamma(2) = 1! = 1$.  $\beta^\alpha = 1^2 = 1$.  $x^{\alpha-1} = x^{2-1} = x$.  $e^{-x/\beta} = e^{-x/1} = e^{-x}.$  Therefore, the gamma density becomes $xe^{-x}$ as shown.

But since we can't see *your* work, how are we supposed to know where you might have had a misunderstanding?  That would be the most helpful thing, ideally.

In general, for positive integers $n$, $\Gamma(n) = (n-1)!$.

Comment: thanks for the help, I will definitely try to learn how to typeset my work.

Comment: You are welcome.  One way I found that really helped me to learn how to typeset math formulas on this site is to right-click on any math expression I see in a post that I want to learn how to typeset, and a little menu will pop up.  Select the first item, "Show Math As..." and then select "TeX commands."  This will display the actual commands that were used to generate the expression.  To recreate it, enclose that command in dollar signs (one each at the beginning and end).  It's really useful when I see a new symbol or equation I don't know how to typeset.